# How to access blob in private storage account in azure function using Powershell

Tags: azure, function, powershell

Need to get metadata from blob URL..I am able to get it with public access, but need to get it if the storage account access level is private..

Created a Azure function with Powershell and running this script and getting this error.

`PublicAccessNotPermitted`Public access is not permitted on this storage account.

This is the Powershell script that gives me the metadata(getting error for Private storage account):
&"D:\Projects\test\MediaInfo.exe" -Open 'Bloburl'

I also tried with SAS token with blob url but it did not work.

Comment: What exactly is `MediaInfo.exe`? Also please tell us about the error you're getting when using a SAS token.

Comment: MediaInfo.exe gives the metadata of media files..

When I use SAS Token it still gives me the error message :

<Error><Code>PublicAccessNotPermitted</Code><Message>Public access is not permitted on this storage account.

Although I can download the file when I ping it in browser with SAS token

Comment: My guess is that there's nothing wrong with the SAS token because you're able to access the file via browser. You will need to check how MediaInfo.exe file is handling your SAS URL.